# Treeview highlight a node @ runtime

Tags: delphi, treeview

I am trying to figure out how to highlight a node on a treeview at runtime, I know the node index but cannot see how I can select it in Code. Also how can I collapse any other open node's and expand the selected one in code

thanks

Comment: Please don't put tag information (for instance, `Delphi`) in your subject line; that's what tags are designed to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Collapse the Treeview using the the [FullCollapse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.FullCollapse) method

```
TreeView1.FullCollapse;
```

2) To Select (highlight) a Node assign the [Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.Selected) property

```
TreeView1.Selected:=TreeView1.Items[NodeIndex];
```

3) Expand the selected Node  using the `Expand` method

```
TreeView1.Items[NodeIndex].Expand(True);
```